# C++ - what affects the order of call stack?

Tags: c++, callstack

I'm so confused with the order of pushing and poping elements of a call stack. I created and initialized a `static int* ptr` in the `void first()`. **NOTE**: I know something unexpected may happen. But what confuses me is that what a call stack does to the recently used address(es).

When the program enters the function call `first()` in the level of `second()`, the varibale `int a` is at the address where `int x` was before. But after adding the line `int z = 99;` in the function `second()`, the variable `a` still stays in the address `ptr` points to.

Now something weird happens. If I get rid of the line `std::cout << " &a = " << &a << std::endl;`, `*ptr` will become 99 which means variable `z` is sitting at where `x` was when I debug or run it again .

I think, the `ptr` will never be put into the call stack cos it's a static variable and it stays in the data segment, which means `ptr` never affects the call stack. Therefore, the first-initialised variable in the function `second()` will be always sitting at where the first-initialised variable in the function `first()` was, no matter what.

I've got lost under this situation.

**Without `int z = 99`:**

```
void first() {
    int x = 7;
    static int* ptr = &x; 
}

void second() {
    int a = 5; // &a = (&x before)
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 3;
    int e = 4;
    std::cout << " &a = " << &a << std::endl;
    first(); 
}


int main()
{
    first();
    second();
    first();
}
```

**With `int z = 99`:**

```
void first() {
    int x = 7;
    static int* ptr = &x;
}

void second() {
    int z = 99;
    int a = 5; // &a = (&x before)
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 3;
    int e = 4;
    std::cout << " &a = " << &a << std::endl;
    first(); 
}


int main()
{
    first();
    second();
    first();
}
```

**Without `std::cout` statement:**

```
void first() {
    int x = 7;
    static int* ptr = &x;
}

void second() {
    int z = 99; // &z = (&x before)
    int a = 5;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 3;
    int e = 4;
    first(); 
}


int main()
{
    first();
    second();
    first();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the compiler is allowed to operate under the "as-if rule", which says that during compilation/optimization it is allowed to make any changes to your program it wants to make, as long as your program's observable behavior afterwards is the same as it would have been otherwise.  So in this case you never use `z` for anything; so it's entirely likely that the compiler simply omitted `z` from the compiled program entirely.  Try printing out the address of `z` as well as `a`,  to force the compiler's hand, and see how that changes things.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it makes sense, thanks